# How can I get the position and draw rectangle using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, opencv3.0

I want to get a position when move and click mouse in picturebox. **I want to create rectangle in the image window when and where a mouse is clicked.**

*I have a simple code from document*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
 
void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
    if ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
    {
        cout << "Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;    
    }
    else if( event == EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN )
    {
        cout << "Right button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
    }
    else if( event == EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN )
    {
        cout << "Middle button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
    }
    else if ( event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE )
    {
        cout << "Mouse move over the window - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool isDragging = false;

    // Read image from file 
    Mat img = imread("input/pic1.jpg");

    //if fail to read the image
    if( img.empty() ) 
    { 
        cout << "Error loading the image" << endl;
        return -1; 
    }

    //Create a window
    namedWindow("My Window", 1);

    //set the callback function for any mouse event
    setMouseCallback("My Window", CallBackFunc, NULL);

    //show the image
    imshow("My Window", img);

    // Wait until user press some key
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

**It working on windows form =, but I want to use mouse clicks. I put the code on GUI. It throws the following error:**

> Error  3   error C3867: 'ProjectFinal::MyForm::CallBackFunc': function call missing argument list; use '&ProjectFinal::MyForm::CallBackFunc' to create a pointer to member c:\users\nungningz\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\projectfinal\projectfinal\MyForm.h 690 1   ProjectFinal
>
> Error  6   error C3867: 'ProjectFinal::MyForm::CallBackFunc': function call missing argument list; use '&ProjectFinal::MyForm::CallBackFunc' to create a pointer to member c:\users\nungningz\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\projectfinal\projectfinal\MyForm.h 690 1   ProjectFinal
>
> 7   IntelliSense: a pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class  c:\Users\NungNingZ\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProjectFinal\ProjectFinal\MyForm.h 690 37  ProjectFinal

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It looks like the code you posted does not match with the errors you posted. The code you posted compiles and runs fine for me. Please post the actual code that is showing those errors.

Comment: the code in topic is fine for me too but fine on windowsForms.Normally I will test and develop a simple code with windowsForm before use. when I apply code on project with Gui .it have a problem. which must be push a parameter in  setMouseCallback("My Window", CallBackFunc, NULL); I can't solve the problem .  help me plz

Answer (score 2):

So you have a problem unrelated to your question.

However, you can achieve your goal using only OpenCV highgui facilites:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

vector<Rect> rects;
bool bDraw;
Rect r;
Point base;

Mat3b img;
Mat3b layer;
Mat3b working;


void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
    if ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
    {
        cout << "Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;    

        // Init your rect
        base.x = x;
        base.y = y;
        r.x = x;
        r.y = y;
        r.width = 0;
        r.height = 0;
        bDraw = true;
    }        
    else if ( event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE )
    {
        cout << "Mouse move over the window - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;

        // If drawing, update rect width and height
        if(!bDraw) return;

        int dx = abs(r.x - x);
        int dy = abs(r.y - y);

        if(x < base.x) {
            r.x = x;
            r.width = abs(x - base.x);
        } else {
            r.width = dx;
        }

        if(y < base.y) {
            r.y = y;
            r.height = abs(y - base.y);
        } else {
            r.height = dy;
        }

        // Refresh
        working = layer.clone();
        rectangle(working, r, Scalar(0,255,0));
        imshow("My Window", working);
    }
    else if ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        cout << "Left button released" << endl;

        // Save rect, draw it on layer
        rects.push_back(r);
        rectangle(layer, r, Scalar(0,255,255));

        r = Rect(); 
        bDraw = false;

        // Refresh
        working = layer.clone();
        rectangle(working, r, Scalar(0,255,0));
        imshow("My Window", working);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool bDraw = false;
    bool isDragging = false;

    // Read image from file 
    img = imread("path_to_image");

    // initialize your temp images
    layer = img.clone();
    working = img.clone();

    //if fail to read the image
    if( img.empty() ) 
    { 
        cout << "Error loading the image" << endl;
        return -1; 
    }

    //Create a window
    namedWindow("My Window", 1);

    //set the callback function for any mouse event
    setMouseCallback("My Window", CallBackFunc, NULL);

    //show the image
    imshow("My Window", working);

    // Wait until user presses 'q'
    while((waitKey(1) & 0xFF) != 'q');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you senior .it code working on simple windows form find ,but push it in gui it not ok and have error

Comment: This answer your question, which is not about forms. You probably have issues specific to the gui you're using, and you're probably better ask a new question specifically for that (with the actual code this time)

Answer (score 0):

In `tracking` module of `opencv-contrib`, there is a nice feature of [`selectROI`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga2e2256794d0c88f4cfc4fdd7890c9794).

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
// selectROI is part of tracking API
#include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main (int argc, char **arv)
{
    // Read image
    Mat im = imread("image.jpg");

    // Select ROI
    Rect2d r = selectROI(im, false); // false -> for creating rectangle from 
                                     //          top-left to bottom-right

    // Crop image
    Mat imCrop = im(r);

    // Display Cropped Image
    imshow("Image", imCrop);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Use the mouse to select the ROI(region of interest) and then press `SPACE` or `ENTER` button. Cancel the selection process by pressing `c` button.