# Opencv in python: grabcut way too slow. Thinking about cropping an image with mouse first and then using grabcut

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on using some image processing techniques to extract an object, with python. The code I am following is based on here.
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/grabcut.py

However,the algorithm is waaaay to slow. Therefore what I am thinking is that I first let the user crop a smaller rectangular region of interest, then running the code on grabcut.

I have two questions:

1. Will this speed up the grabcut process?
2. If so, what is the simplest way of letting user draw a rectangle and crop it out? The problem here is the "onmouse" cannot return anything, otherwise I can take advantage of the code already existing to draw the rectangle.

Thanks

Comment: 1) Yes, smaller images means less time. You can always run grabcut on a resized image. 2) You can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31376558/5008845). It's C++ for drawing rects using OpenCV highgui. You can translate it in python, or find something similar on the web.

Comment: great thank you for your comment. Yes I think writing another chunk of code just to crop is not too hard; but it is kind of wasteful as the original code in the link already contains some code for drawing rectangle... I was thinking maybe adding a few lines in the original would do; but it has not be successful..