# Tracking mouse movements for drawing labels in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, mousemove

I am new to c++ and Opencv.
I am trying to detect the mouse coordinates when I click the left button of the mouse, and if such coordinates are within a certain area of the image, it draws a rectangle using the current mouse coordinates as the top-left vertex.

Here is the implementation:

```
void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void * userdata)
{

if(event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN || event == EVENT_LBUTTONUP)

{
       mouseX=x;
       mouseY = y;
      `
        if(( mouseX >= 0 &&  mouseX <= 130) && ( mouseY >= 22 &&  mouseY  <=301))  
        {
         rectangle(img,Point(mouseX, mouseY),Point(mouseX+30, mouseY+ 40),Scalar(0,0,0),1,8);
        }
   }
```

It will store the coordinates, but it seems that it never executes the inner if statement.

Comment: Two if statements are there..!! When the condition is not true obviously it will not.!! Firstly consider an entire image coordinate values and try.It should draw a rectangle when you click on an image.  I can't work with this piece of code.!!

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31376558/5008845) solution

Comment: @Miki Thank you. I will study the solution

Comment: @Arjun I will go with your suggestion.

Comment: @Miki Why did you define another two copies of the same image?