# Opencv Error: Assertion failed in imshow function for clicking operation

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I have the following code in which I am loading the image and want to generate a ROI image based upon the selection of the mouse event.

```
    void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && !drag)
    {
        point1 = Point(x, y);
        drag = 1;
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && drag)
    {
        Mat img1 = img.clone();
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rectangle(img1, point1, point2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3, 8, 0);
        imshow("image", img1);
        waitKey(0);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP && drag)
    {
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rect = Rect(point1.x,point1.y,x-point1.x,y-point1.y);
        drag = 0;
        roiImg = img(rect);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        select_flag = 1;
        drag = 0;
    }
}
int main()
{


    Mat img = imread("C:\\Users\\ashutosh\\Downloads\\Documents\\Experiments\\PL_Pizza\\0001.jpg");
    if (!img.data)
        {
            std::cout << "Image not loaded";
            return -1;
        }
   // imshow("image",img);
    while(1)
    {
        cvSetMouseCallback("image", mouseHandler, NULL);
        if (select_flag == 1)
        {
            imshow("ROI", roiImg); 
        }
        rectangle(img, rect, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3, 8, 0);
        imshow("image", img);
        k = waitKey(10);
        if (k == 27)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I receive the following error again and again:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file C:\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 281. This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information.
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     What():  C:\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:281: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

Please help me out. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Looks like the path to your image may be invalid.  Are you sure there's a documents folder inside your downloads folder? imread() doesn't throw an error when an image is not found, it simply leaves the Mat object with zero rows and columns

Comment: Yes @Dziugas, its there and I checked it myself. The image loads but when I click anywhere on the image, the program stops working !!

Comment: I won't debug your code, but you can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31376558/5008845) working code.. ;D

Comment: Please edit your question to show the [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) amount of code that reproduces your problem. Right now your code won't compile, since it's missing some declarations. That being said, the line `imshow("image", img1);` is suspect to me. You're cloning `img`, but it doesn't exist in that scope. I'd guess you have a static `Mat img` somewhere that never gets any data placed in it, causing the crash.