# Python OpenCV - Draw a proper resizing Rectangle

Tags: python, opencv

I've been trying this code where I have an image, then I can draw a rectangle based on when I click and drag the mouse. On Mouse Down event, I mark the x and y coordinates as the initial corner for the rectangle. On the Mouse Move, I draw the rectangle from the old x and y coordinates I saved, to the new one where the mouse is. Finally, on the Mouse Up, I draw the rectangle as final.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing = False # True if mouse is pressed
mode = True # if True, draw rectangle. Press 'm' to toggle to curve
ix, iy = -1, -1

# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global ix, iy, drawing, mode, overlay, output, alpha
    overlay = img.copy()
    output = img.copy()
    alpha = 0.5

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix, iy = x, y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            if mode == True:
                cv2.rectangle(overlay, (ix, iy), (x, y), (0, 255, 0), -1)
                cv2.addWeighted(overlay, alpha, output, 1 - alpha, 0, img)
                cv2.imshow('image', img)
            else:
                cv2.circle(overlay, (x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        if mode == True:
            cv2.rectangle(overlay, (ix, iy), (x, y), (0, 255, 0), -1)
            cv2.addWeighted(overlay, alpha, output, 1 - alpha, 0, img)

        else:
            cv2.circle(overlay, (x, y), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)


##img = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), np.uint8)
# Get our image
img = cv2.imread("bed_cv.jpg", 1)

#make cv2 windows, set mouse callback
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', draw_circle)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image', img)

    # This is where we get the keyboard input
    # Then check if it's "m" (if so, toggle the drawing mode)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == ord('m'):
        mode = not mode
    elif k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Of course the problem here is that if I start at the center, then drag to the bottom right, then go back to the bottom left, the first rectangle doesn't get erased. Of course this happens because I'm actually drawing the rectangle on the image and not clearing it, so every rectangle that is created on the Mouse Move event gets drawn.

The effect I want to achieve is similar when you're drawing a box over your desktop and you can go around change directions without having the rectangle made.

My question is, is it possible to draw a rectangle visually but not write it to the image yet?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31376558/5008845). I usually keep a copy of the original image, an image with all the rectangles already drawn (layer copy) and a copy of the layer copy where I draw the "partial rectangle" I'm creating now (working copy), and draw the rectangle on the working copy only. On the mouseUp, I save the working copy as the new layer copy

Comment: @Miki thanks for the hint! I managed to do it. I'll be posting code shortly.

Comment: An alternate option would be to use some reversible operation. If it's an outline, then you could draw it with XOR operation (although with OpenCV you probably need to use the line iterator to do so). For a filled rectangle, you could invert the ROI. Of course this won't look the same, but it's an approach that avoids the necessity to keep a copy of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The idea was to make a copy of the image (in this case, img2), and then use that as the output for the overlays in the Mouse Move event. Then use the original image (in this case, img), on the button up event:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing = False # True if mouse is pressed
mode = True # if True, draw rectangle. Press 'm' to toggle to curve
ix, iy = -1, -1

# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global ix, iy, drawing, mode, overlay, output, alpha
    overlay = img.copy()
    output = img.copy()
    alpha = 0.5

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix, iy = x, y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            if mode == True:
                cv2.rectangle(overlay, (ix, iy), (x, y), (0, 255, 0), -1)
                cv2.addWeighted(overlay, alpha, output, 1 - alpha, 0, img2)
                cv2.imshow('image', img2)
            else:
                cv2.circle(overlay, (x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        if mode == True:
            cv2.rectangle(overlay, (ix, iy), (x, y), (0, 255, 0), -1)
            cv2.addWeighted(overlay, alpha, output, 1 - alpha, 0, img)

        else:
            cv2.circle(overlay, (x, y), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)


##img = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), np.uint8)
# Get our image
img = cv2.imread("bed_cv.jpg", 1)
img2 = img.copy()

#make cv2 windows, set mouse callback
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', draw_circle)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image', img2)

    # This is where we get the keyboard input
    # Then check if it's "m" (if so, toggle the drawing mode)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == ord('m'):
        mode = not mode
    elif k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```